# CIFaceFeature iOS 12 beta bugs

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, ios12, cidetector

CIFaceFeature's hasSmile boolean is not working properly on iOS 12 beta.

The hasSmile boolean always has a value of false and thus isn't detecting smiles properly.

In addition the eyes positions are incorrect.

Is there a known fix to this bug?

Comment: make sure CIDetectorSmile is present and true in the dictionary passed to   `features(in:options:)` method

Comment: @LeoDabus I already did that. It worked totally fine on my devices in iOS 11. Always reporting false on the iOS 12 Beta.

Comment: @LeoDabus Actually I've found out all the booleans for CIFaceFeature are showing false. Might be a big iOS 12 issue.

Comment: For me CIDetector gives wrong eyes location, just on IOS 12...

Comment: @EdiZ Does smile detection work properly?

Comment: @AryamanGoel The smile detection doesn't work properly when running on IOS 12. It always return false.

Comment: Report it to Apple, they won’t read it here and won’t fix it before the final release

Comment: @jcesarmobile I did several times, doesn't seem to be fixed yet

Comment: Finally they fixed that. The eyes detection is now ok with the latest IOS 12 beta (6)